# Amazon AWS tutorial - Cannot redirect to service provided destination - try using AWS keys for authentication or check destination URL

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, scaling

I'm following the Amazon AWS tutorial and I have reached **Step 6: Launch Amazon EC2 Instances Using Auto Scaling**
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/

But when I run the launch command:

```
as-create-launch-config MyLC --image-id ami-7813e011 --instance-type t1.micro --group webappsecuritygroup --key mykeypair.pem
```

I get the following error:

```
 Cannot redirect to service provided destination - try using AWS keys for
 authentication (instead of X509/Private key) or check destination URL
```

What have I done wrong? I created the key as stated in the management console.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I removed:

```
export AWS_AUTO_SCALING_URL=https://autoscaling.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

and added:

```
export EC2_REGION=eu-west-1
```

in **.profile** and it worked like a charm!